# Typescript: Specifying an Object MUST have ONE or BOTH key-value pairs

Tags: typescript

This is for hypothetical purposes. Let's say we have this example Person type:

```
// example type definition - i know this would not pass the check
type Person = {
    firstName?:  string;
    lastName?: string;
}
```

And I want all of the following inputs to be correct:

CORRECT INPUTS

```
{ firstName: 'John' }, 
{ lastName: 'Wayne' }, 
{ firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Wayne' }
```

And the following to not be correct:

NOT CORRECT INPUTS

```
{ firstName: 'John', middleName: 'Bob', lastName: 'Wayne' }
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: can you show us an example of what you have not working?

Answer (score 0):

For this simple case depicted, a Union case of two types requiring either of the two works quite nicely:

```
type RequiredFirstName = { firstName: string; lastName?: string }
type RequiredLastName = { firstName?: string; lastName: string }

type Person = RequiredFirstName | RequiredLastName;

const a: Person = { firstName: 'John' }; 
const b: Person = { lastName: 'Wayne' }; 
const c: Person = { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Wayne' };
const d: Person = {};
const e: Person = { firstName: 'John', middleName: 'Bob', lastName: 'Wayne' };
```

[(Playground)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShCOBXAlgJwgEwGJoM7ADkBDAW2gF4oBvKAMz0NIgC4p9VkA7AcwG4oANkXzEyAflbsu3KAF8AUKEiwEKdBgAywxmSiUa9VCKYS2wDj35DjZSeelz5i8NAAKEIwHtOelUjSYOEY60AA+fmqYWjYQvE4Axt74UESs7l4++nQMoixQAOQAUp4AFpz5cvzyiZzJAEZpHrjevjTWIaz5AOpEIJwQFbJVNcnxjRmt2cG5ncVl+QA0gtozBT19A5XVScBQGOPNmdRD27W7eemHk4Yxs6XlSyTIGBgCEKv5AEKedYvLt2tev1BnEgA)

`a`, `b` and `c` are all valid.
`d` fails because it doesn't fit either of the sides of the union type.
`e` fails because more properties are defined than present in the union type.

To be fair, this does not scale well but I am sure there are more skillful TypeScript users who will come up with a generic type to convert one type into one matching your specifications.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution - (from u/ybogomolov on Reddit):

```
type AtLeastOne<T, Keys extends keyof T = keyof T> = Partial<T> & { readonly [K in Keys]: Required<Pick<T, K>> }[Keys];

type Person = AtLeastOne<{
    readonly firstName: string;
    readonly lastName: string;
}>;

const user1: Person = {}; // ❌ Property 'lastName' is missing in type '{}'
const user2: Person = { firstName: "John" }; // ✅
const user3: Person = { lastName: "Wayne" }; // ✅
const user4: Person = { firstName: "John", lastName: "Wayne" }; // ✅
const user5: Person = { firstName: "John", middleName: 'Bob', lastName: "Wayne" }; // ❌ Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'middleName' does not exist in type 'Person'
```